# PowerShell: Unable to write data to a UNC path that contains square brackets

Tags: powershell, unc

This is the problem I'm having:

```
# The following line works
Add-Content -LiteralPath "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\[Test].txt" -Value "This is a test"

# The following line does not work and does not output an error message
Add-Content -LiteralPath "\\Server\Share\[Test].txt" -Value "This is a test"
```

I have already checked my permissions and I definitely have permission to write to the network share. The problem only happens when I use the "LiteralPath" parameter, which, unfortunately, is required for what I'm doing.

How can I write data to a UNC path that contains square brackets?

Comment: That is bizarre, it should work but I can duplicate your issue as well

Comment: Interesting. I could not duplicate this.

Comment: I am curious - why is using the -LiteralPath switch required?

Comment: @zdan Which OS are you running for both the computer running the script and the computer hosting the network share?

Comment: @Goyuix "LiteralPath" is required because the files I am working with have square brackets in their filenames and I cannot change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you will find on [Microsoft web site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx) an explanation about strange behaviours of '*sqare brackets*' in PowerShell expressions.

**BUT**

When I just write the following (without brackets) it just does't work for me :

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath "\\server\share\temp\test.txt" -Value "coucou"
```

but (according to Microsoft article) the following works

```
Set-Content -Path "\\server\share\temp\test.txt" -Value "coucou"
set-content -path '\\server\share\temp\`[test`].txt' -Value "coucou"
```

I tried to solve this trouble with PowerShell Drive

```
New-PSDrive -Name u -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\server\share"
```

And it was even worst

```
Set-Content : Impossible de trouver une partie du chemin d'accès '\\server\share\server\share\server\share\temp\test.txt'.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 12
+ set-content <<<<  -literalpath "u:\temp\test.txt" -Value "coucou"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\server\shar...e\temp\test.txt:String) [Set-Content], DirectoryNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterDirectoryNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

**Turn arround solution 1 :**
I solve it using :

```
net use u: \\server\share
set-content -literalpath "u:\temp\test.txt" -Value "coucou"
```

And then the followwing works

```
set-content -literalpath "u:\temp\[test].txt" -Value "coucou"
```

**Turn arround solution 2** : [using FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

```
# Create the file
set-content -path '\\server\share\temp\`[test`].txt' -Value "coucou"
# Get a FileInfo
$fic = Get-Item '\\server\share\temp\`[test`].txt'
# Get a stream Writer
$sw = $fic.AppendText()
# Append what I need
$sw.WriteLine("test")
# Don't forget to close the stream writter
$sw.Close()
```

I think that the explanation is that in `-literalpath` UNC are poorly supported

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure that with your code I can get my script working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The wildcarding of the square brackets seems to only be implemented in the -path parameter of the cmdlets.  The default method of the fileinfo object still considers them literals:

```
 $fic = [io.directoryinfo]"\\server\share\temp\[test].txt"
```

Comment: in my test even without a file with square brackets the UNC name is not supported in -literalPath parameter, can you have a look please ?

Comment: PS C:\testfiles> get-item -literalpath "\\localhost\c$\testfiles\test[4].txt"


    Directory: \\localhost\c$\testfiles


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---          5/8/2011  10:35 AM         12 test[4].txt


PS C:\testfiles>

Comment: try set-content to create a new file with an UNC name